# Using RegExp, count sentences in a paragraph based on periods, question marks, and exclamation points

Tags: javascript

So far, I have:

```
function countSentences(paragraph) {
    var regex = new RegExp(`^(?=.*[.?!])[.?!]$`, 'gi');
    count = 0;

    while (regex.exec(paragraph)) {
        count++
    }
    return count;
}
```

Whenever I type in a paragraph in the function, it just returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your regex like this

```js
function count(str){
 return ( str.match( RegExp(`[.?!]`, 'gi') ) || [] ).length;
}
console.log(count("This is good. But is it? you decide!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start you don't really need the RegExp constructor as you're not building a dynamic pattern, so we can use a RegExp literal.

Secondly, you're complicating it. You simply need to look for instances of the relevant punctuation symbols - no need for look-aheads or the like.

```
function count(paragraph) {
    return (paragraph.match(/[.?!]{1,}/g) || []).length;
}
```

Note, this also guards against sentences that end with overly expressive punctuation patterns like `???` or `!?`.